# Why does this code snippet compile?

Tags: c

Why does the following code compile?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    getchar;
}
```

Comment: Because its error-free?

Comment: It basically boils down to whether `getchar` is allowed to be a macro. If it is, the code may not be correct.

Comment: This question is embarrassing. What a moron I was three years ago.

Comment: @missingfaktor not really - it's a valid question. I'd expect an `Expression with possibly no effect` or other warning (at least), but such is life.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Because function names are aliases to function pointers to those functions, which are themselves values much like integers..  This is semantically very similar to

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    42;
}
```

It is valid but pointless.

Comment: And very annoying!!!! typing, "int x = getX" instead of "x = getX()" will work quite happily and put some random address value into x.

Comment: I hate C. >_<  [15 char filler]

Comment: @Rahul: That's not a very *polyglot* like attitude!

Comment: @Tarydon - is the word polyglot correct when dealing with typed (not spoken) languages?

Comment: @jball : http://blogs.computerworld.com/15032/polyglot_programming_development_in_multiple_languages

Comment: @Martin Beckett:Any decent compiler will issue a warning for such an assignment. If yours doesn't, get a better one (or quit disabling all the warnings -- especially in C, you should usually enable all warnings, and treat them as errors.

Comment: @Rahul - Polyglot it is! I've always associated polyglot with spoken and multilingual with written (and therefore code), but it appears that I was putting meanings into the words that wasnt' there.

Comment: @Jerry: A **decent** compiler would issue an error, since the C language does not permit implicit conversions between integer and pointer types. Unfortunately most real-world compilers lack basic decency...

Comment: @R: At least from my viewpoint, that's a distinction without a difference. As noted in my comment, I think warnings should be treated as errors anyway...

Answer (score 13):

The same reason `1;` would compile,  `getchar` is just an address to a function.  The result is evaluated, then discarded.  In the language specification, it's called an "expression statement";

Answer (score 2):

C is weird, this code compiles too, but it segfaults
which for the record, is the smallest segfault in C
history.

```
main;
```